# D: Converting DateTime to Date: cannot cast from DateTime to Date

Tags: datetime, casting, d

I need to convert DateTime type to Date. here is my code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 14, 10, 13);
Date z = cast(Date)dt;
```

`Error: cannot cast from DateTime to Date`

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DateTime isn't a Date, you can't cast it. To convert, simply access the `DateTime.date()` property:

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_datetime.html#.DateTime.date

> const pure nothrow @property @safe Date date();
>
> ```
> The date portion of DateTime.
> ```